How to Compile Java Classes at Runtime Without Saving to the Filesystem?
I'm developing a Java application where I need to compile Java code provided as a String at runtime. I know that using the JavaCompiler API from javax.tools allows for dynamic compilation, but most examples involve writing the source code to a .java file on the filesystem.
(As suggested here, for instance.)
I want to avoid any disk I/O operations. Is it possible to compile Java classes entirely in memory, without saving the source code or compiled class files to the filesystem?
I don't need to load the compiled class into a class loader — I only need the raw compiled bytecode. Any code examples or guidance on achieving in-memory compilation would be greatly appreciated!

If you don't want to load the class, what are you planning to do with the compiled binary? The JShell API might be suitable depending on what you are going to do with it.

The documentation of javax.tools.JavaCompiler has an example of implementing a JavaFileObject subclass that holds the source code in a string field.

Also see Compile code fully in memory with javax.tools.JavaCompiler [duplicate]
